# Restrict movement area of QGraphicsItem inside of polygon area

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I am trying to limit the movement of QGraphicsItem inside of a parent object inherited from QGraphicsPathItem that has an arbitrary complex shape (not square).

As I understand, I should extract each point of the moving object and check whether each of them is not contained in the parent QPainterPath. Then split the parent QPainterPath into small rectangle-shaped polygons and restrict movement area in the bounding box of each sub polygon.

So, I would like to know if there are any other options to exist. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can check on QGraphicsItem move event if it is still inside QGraphicsPathItem.

The check itself, you can do it with this [QGraphicsItem method](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#collidesWithItem):

```
bool QGraphicsItem::collidesWithItem(const QGraphicsItem * other, Qt::ItemSelectionMode mode = Qt::IntersectsItemShape) const
```

And to be sure that item is still fully enclosed inside its parent, set the [mode](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemSelectionMode-enum) to `Qt::ContainsItemShape`

If it is false, return QGraphicsItem to its previous position

EDIT: this check returns if QGraphicsItems **shape** is inside other QGraphicsItems **shape**, not its bounding box.